# GCP Generative AI - How can I refer my existing prompts from python code without sending full prompt contents in each requests?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Though GCP Gen AI studio features are in previews and app builders are unavailable to all except for a trusted tester program group, I have a question about a specific requirement.

I have a prompt that I have deployed, which is visible in the section My prompts. But is there any way I can refer to it from my code to call that prompt without even sending the content of the entire prompt during each request?

Comment: AFAIK, no. The save prompt is only for convenience. If you want to use it, you have to get it from the prompt library, and then submit the content (of the saved prompt) to your model. But, it's an interesting feature. to have a prompt registry as you have a model registry today!

Comment: Yes, that's what it seems. Maybe they will have it in the near future.

Comment: Hi @ARINDAM BANERJEE, did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

At this point, you don't have a method/object on the [Vertex AI GenAI SDK](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/vertexai.preview.language_models.TextGenerationModel) to recover the prompts you save in the console.

You can see that still on the console, you your saved prompt screen, if you click the "view code" button on the upper right, the code snippet you simply resend the saved prompt details on the requests.

If you have a very specific context to be passed, and it is too large to be sent every time, you may consider [creating a tuned model](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/generative-ai/models/tune-models) from the foundation model - if you have enough data to run a tune job, you will have a model version which will know all the directions are critical for you.